# As a site collection administrator I am not able to access site settings on site collection

Tags: sharepoint-2013

As a collection administrator I am not able  to access site settings on SharePoint site collection. if I click on site settings it showing "sorry, this site has doesn't share with you". But I login using site collection administrator account on dev server.

If I create new site collection with same web application I can access everything. one more thing I restored production database on this server and I associated with this web application.

I hope anyone can help to this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen as the production environment will have different users and when you restore it to your development environment, your development environment changes were override.

To fix this issue, go to Central Administration -> Application management. Under site collection section, click on "Change site collection administrators".

[image: Application management]

In this select your site collection. Change site collection administrator and click ok.

[image: Change site collection administrator]

Comment: same thing i did but still i am facing same issue

Comment: Please make sure you add your user in primary site collection administrator (not the secondary). Also please check your user have permission in content database.